# Changing “index.php” Within The Address

Tags: php

I am developing a website in which i want to change my page localhost/home.php into page localhost/home/

I tried this .htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php page=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: You can also Use DirectoryIndex instead of url rewrite . something like DirectoryIndex home.php index.php index.html site-down.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove .php extension for a particular page
                                                                                         `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`
`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteRule ^(home)$ home.php  [L,NC]`
`</IfModule>`